# Compatibilty issue of pyexiv2 and ctypes module in QGIS 3.10

Tags: pyqgis, installation, osgeo4w, library

I'm trying to install a python module called `pyexiv2` onto QGIS 3.10, I've noticed this module doesn't work. Although the module's installation seems to process well `python -m install pyexiv2`
and I get confirm the installation was done.  `Requirement already satisfied: pyexiv2 in c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages (1.3.0)` , we are not able to `import pyexiv2` in PyQGIS without getting an error :

> OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found

I've tried  OSGeo4W network installation, QGIS 3.10 standalone but nothing works, **exept with QGIS 3.4** : this issue only appears from QGIS 3.10

As suggested I've tried the `p3exiv2` [module](https://pypi.org/project/py3exiv2) but the PYPI package is not designed for iOS & Linux only, that is why it seems not possible to install it. Except... by using another [p3exiv2 module adapted for windows](https://gist.github.com/ksdme/190f91b33ca1138b0ff85ab662c02e6a) but this one requires some Windows packages like GIT & VCPKG (MS Visual Studio)... and I was not able to install it.

I've then contacted `pyexiv2`'s author and he found where the issue was from. *We are waiting for a new version of pyexiv2 next month that may (or may not) solve the issue.*

**Bug Recurrence Steps**

1. Install `pyexiv2` using the Python interpreter that comes with QGIS3.10 : `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\python.exe" -m pip install pyexiv2`
2. I can execute the following command successfully, in the Python interpreter that comes with QGIS3.10 ::

   ```
    C:\Users\Leo>"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\python.exe"
    Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import os
    >>> import ctypes
    >>> dll_dir = r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pyexiv2\lib'        # This is where pyexiv2 is installed
    >>> ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(dll_dir, "exiv2.dll"))
    <CDLL 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pyexiv2\lib\exiv2.dll', handle 7ffe9ad90000 at 0x23702c3b9e8>
    >>> ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(dll_dir, "api.dll"))
    <CDLL 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pyexiv2\lib\api.dll', handle 7ffee1920000 at 0x23702c55908>
   ```
3. But I failed to execute the same code in the GUI of QGIS3.10 :

   ```
    Python Console
    Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
    Security warning: typing commands from an untrusted source can lead to data loss and/or leak
    import os
    import ctypes
    dll_dir = r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pyexiv2\lib'
    ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(dll_dir, "exiv2.dll"))
    <CDLL 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pyexiv2\lib\exiv2.dll', handle 7ffea62d0000 at 0x26cd89b0860>
    ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(dll_dir, "api.dll"))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
      exec(code, self.locals)
     File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
      self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found.
   ```

**Conclusion :**

The reason may be that the DLL used by QGIS3.10 conflicts with `ctypes`.
The author is going release a new version of `pyexiv2` that could solve the issue but nothing sure. 
I don't know how we can report this issue to QGIS team and if we should?

About using `py3exiv2` instead of `pyexiv2` : that could be another solution but I failed (but I'm newbie !).

Comment: Have you try this module? https://pypi.org/project/py3exiv2/

Comment: I'm not able to instal it. after this cmd: python3 -m pip install py3exiv2 , It collects well datas, but I get error: Command errored  out with exit statut 1

Comment: You can't use QGIS 3.4 but can you try to install it on this version to see if the problem comes from the QGIS version?

Comment: pyexiv2 works with QGIS 3.4 (stand alone and network). The issue seems only appeared with the last QGIS 3.10 (I've tried with both standalone & network instal).
The other approach with py3exiv2 is also very complex, since the pypi script only works with linux & ios.  I' contacted the author, that's how I get this https://gist.github.com/ksdme/190f91b33ca1138b0ff85ab662c02e6a
but again... this solution doesn't work, it requierts GIT & VCPKG and after two days faced to this issue.... my brain is firing. any way The best way should be to make pyexiv2 working into QGIS 3.10 ...

Comment: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ ist the place to report an issue. You'll need to create an account first and then report by creating a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with pyexiv2, I can install, but when I import the library script crash.

I found a solution using the library exif:

https://pypi.org/project/exif/

It's so easy to use, and with Qgis I don,'t have any problem.

In this code I insert GPS coordinates to a snapshot of screen:

```
from exif import Image
with open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    my_image = Image(image_file)

my_image.make = "Python"
my_image.gps_latitude_ref=exif_lat_ref
my_image.gps_latitude=exif_lat
my_image.gps_longitude_ref= exif_lon_ref
my_image.gps_longitude= exif_lon

with open(file_name, 'wb') as new_image_file:
    new_image_file.write(my_image.get_file())
```